# Python currency codes into a list

Tags: python, internationalization, currency

Does anyone have a nifty way to get all the three letter alphabetic currency codes (an example of the ones I mean is at  http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/currency_codes/currency_codes_list-1.htm) into a list in Python 2.5? Note I don't want to do a screen scraping version as the code has to work offline - the website is just an example of the codes.

It looks like there should be a way using the locale library but it's not clear to me from reading the documentation and there must be a better way than copy pasting those into a file!

To clear the question up more, in C# for the same problem, the following code did it very neatly using the internal locale libraries:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)
          .Select(c => new RegionInfo(c.LCID).CurrencySymbol)
          .Distinct()
```

I was hoping there might be an equivalent in python. And thanks to everyone who has provided an answer so far.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/python-money/ ?

Comment: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry/0.12.1

Comment: @delnan thanks for the suggestion and apologies if the question was misleading. I was using the website as an example of the currencies in the ISO list rather than wanting them specifically from that source. The code won't have access to the internet.

Comment: Why do people put answers in comments all the time rather than, you know, in answers

Answer (score 2):

Not very elegant or nifty, but you can generate the list once and save to use it later:

```
import urllib, re
url = "http://www.iso.org/iso/support/faqs/faqs_widely_used_standards/widely_used_standards_other/currency_codes/currency_codes_list-1.htm"
print re.findall(r'\<td valign\="top"\>\s+([A-WYZ][A-Z]{2})\s+\</td\>', urllib.urlopen(url).read())
```

output:

```
['AFN', 'EUR', 'ALL', 'DZD', 'USD', 'EUR', 'AOA', 'ARS', 'AMD', 'AWG', 'AUD',
...
'UZS', 'VUV', 'EUR', 'VEF', 'VND', 'USD', 'USD', 'MAD', 'YER', 'ZMK', 'ZWL', 'SDR']
```

Note that you'll need to prune everything after X.. as they are apparently reserved names, which means that you'll get one rogue entry (SDR, the last element) which you can just delete by yourself.

Comment: that's not what OP is looking for. Why do people never read comments to begin with?

Comment: Thanks Lee but unfortunately the code has to work offline, I know it's not clear in the question so I've tried to make it more apparent.

Comment: i don't understand why Lee Gao's answer is wrong. you can't auto-generate currency codes( there is no algorithm to generate them), so you have to have a list of them. Lee Gao's answer tells you how to generate that list once, then save it and use it in your code.

Comment: Because if it comes from an internal library rather than something I've typed (or scraped myself) it's likely to be maintained for the future (and correct at the start!). Also once I'm getting the list, I can then do more advanced operations like look at corresponding currency symbols using similar code.

Comment: @Richard A data source is far more likely to be up-to-date than a library which gets its data from a data source.

Comment: @marcog It's more about the maintenance. If I do a one off screen scrape, the code won't be maintained. I can't pull it down every time because the code doesn't have internet access. For example in three years when the Argentinian peso becomes the global currency, the good people at python inc. will update their locale library and my code will continue to work.

Comment: @Richard You still need Internet access to update the library when it's updated.

Comment: @marcog not really. Lots of installs are done offline. For example from a CD or usb. This is one of those.

Comment: @Richard Then it's still an out-dated copy of the library, i.e. "unmaintained".

Comment: If the code can't get an up-to-the minute list from the Internet, then you will have to provide offline updates. If you have to provide offline updates, you might as well provide the data as Python code, because it is the easiest to deal with. Rather than providing a data file that you would then have to parse each time your program runs, you would just provide a Python module that defines the data structure directly. (It would be in a separate file specifically so it can be updated easily.)

Comment: sorry Richard, I didn't see your comment, but I do believe that marcog has a point. If you do decide to maintain the currency symbols yourself, you may want to look at his solution as the iso.org markup may change drastically in the future.

Comment: Yes but if I download it once through screen scraping it's unmaintained in two places rather than one (the code and the locale library). If I can depend on the library only, when it changes, my code doesn't. Has decoupling and single source of data advantages. I didn't downvote your answer by the way..

Comment: @Richard I'm not suggesting you screen-scrap once-off. I'm suggesting you store the data file (the one I recommended) and parse it each time the app launches. Then you just need to keep the file updated.

Comment: @kindall How is a huge list within Python code easier to deal with?

Comment: It's easier to deal with in the sense that you don't have to write any code to turn it into a list, because it already is one.

Answer (score 1):

You can get currency codes (and other) data from [geonames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt). Here's some code that downloads the data (save the file locally to achieve the same result offline) and populates a list:

```
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen('http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/countryInfo.txt')
ccodes = []
for line in data.read().split('\n'):
  if not line.startswith('#'):
    line = line.split('\t')
    try:
      if line[10]:
        ccodes.append(line[10])
    except IndexError:
      pass
ccodes = list(set(ccodes))
ccodes.sort()
```